# Console App failing to download file?

Tags: c#, console-application, webclient, download

Started writing a simple console app that downloads a file to the current location. For some reason, no matter how big the file, the WebClient that i'm using only downloads 1kb of the file (no matter how big). I've tried adding a browser to the header, I've tried adding "while (WC.IsBusy)" (a suggestion I found while googling), I've even tried to add an error handler to the completed handler to see what's going on, but that throws "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". I'm pulling my hair out here and I'm hoping someone can see something that I'm not.

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace csgocfgmakerupdater
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                instalwithargs(args);
            }
            else
            {
                installnoargs();
            }
        }

        static void installnoargs()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Current Folder: " + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("This will install the Counter-Strike: Global Offensive Config File Maker to your computer. Please select an option from the following:");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Install to Current Folder");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Install to Custom Folder");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Update Existing Installation in Current Folder");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Update Existing Installation in Custom Folder");
            Console.WriteLine("5. Exit");
            string installcmd = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (installcmd)
            {
                case "1":
                    try
                    {
                        string updurl = "http://cachefly.cachefly.net/100mb.test";//"http://elite.so/projects/cs-go-game-config-editor/CSGOCFGMKR.exe";
                        WebClient WC = new WebClient();
                        WC.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(WC_DownloadProgressChanged);
                        WC.DownloadFileCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventHandler(WC_DownloadFileCompleted);
                        WC.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(updurl), "100mb.test");
//this waits for the webclient to exit 
while (WC.IsBusy) {
Console.WriteLine("Downloading Updated files...");
}
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        static void WC_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.UserState != e.Error)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Update applied successfully!");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
            }
        }

        static void WC_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {  
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Downloading Updated files...");
            Console.WriteLine(progperc.ToString() + "%");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens at the `Console.ReadKey()` line?  Do you/the user press a key and then the WebClient goes out of scope?

Comment: The Console.ReadKey() underneath WC.DownloadFileAsync is reached after the webclient errors. It was put there so the app wouldn't close each time it errored out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. FYI you were using and referencing to Windows Forms specific namespaces here.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace csgocfgmakerupdater
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
             //   instalwithargs(args);
            }
            else
            {
                installnoargs();
            }
        }

        static void installnoargs()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Current Folder: " + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("This will install the Counter-Strike: Global Offensive Config File Maker to your computer. Please select an option from the following:");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Install to Current Folder");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Install to Custom Folder");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Update Existing Installation in Current Folder");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Update Existing Installation in Custom Folder");
            Console.WriteLine("5. Exit");
            string installcmd = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (installcmd)
            {
                case "1":
                    try
                    {
                        string updurl = "http://elite.so/projects/cs-go-game-config-editor/CSGOCFGMKR.exe";
                        WebClient WC = new WebClient();
                        WC.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(WC_DownloadProgressChanged);
                        WC.DownloadFileCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventHandler(WC_DownloadFileCompleted);
                        WC.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(updurl), "100mb.test");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        static void WC_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.UserState != e.Error)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Update applied successfully!");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }

        static void WC_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Downloading Updated files...");
            Console.WriteLine(e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%");
        }
    }
}
```

*Responding to your comment:
Below is the same code which I modified the file URL to check if the file is coming correctly. This is 7+ MB Notepad++ setup i tried as a sample and it downloaded the file in my bin folder successfully much like the previous example did.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace csgocfgmakerupdater
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                //   instalwithargs(args);
            }
            else
            {
                installnoargs();
            }
        }

        static void installnoargs()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Current Folder: " + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("This will install the Counter-Strike: Global Offensive Config File Maker to your computer. Please select an option from the following:");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Install to Current Folder");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Install to Custom Folder");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Update Existing Installation in Current Folder");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Update Existing Installation in Custom Folder");
            Console.WriteLine("5. Exit");
            string installcmd = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (installcmd)
            {
                case "1":
                    try
                    {
                        //string updurl = "http://elite.so/projects/cs-go-game-config-editor/CSGOCFGMKR.exe";
                        string updurl = "http://download.tuxfamily.org/notepadplus/6.5.4/npp.6.5.4.Installer.exe";
                        WebClient WC = new WebClient();
                        WC.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(WC_DownloadProgressChanged);
                        WC.DownloadFileCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventHandler(WC_DownloadFileCompleted);
                        WC.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(updurl),"test.exe");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        static void WC_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.UserState != e.Error)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Update applied successfully!");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }

        static void WC_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Downloading Updated files...");
            Console.WriteLine(e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Please mark as answer if it helped you." is not part of an answer.

Comment: I'll be testing the code in about 10 minutes. I'm on the road at the moment and my coding laptop is at home. Thank god for RDP!

Comment: Same issue, downloads 1kb, then hits an error (that i cant seem to find).

Comment: I tried the same here which gave me a file with 51.5 KB size.

Comment: Ok, when i get back to my laptop i'll make a new project and try it again.

Comment: I've tried it in a new project on 3 different machines, all with the same result. Downloads 1kb then goes to an unknown error.

Answer (score 0):

You exit the program asynchronously before the download terminates.
The `WC.IsBusy` solution seems legit, maybe you should try and post that code, instead.
We'll then see how to fix that.

And an error handler seems a very good idea, you should have one just in case.